# Scope of this site - and type of questions

Tags: discussion

**What type of questions are *more* welcomed here?**

1. The one that ask about basic **ruling of Islamic** about different things such as zakat,Hajj, prayers and so on.
2. Or the ones that are **philosophical** and required some good explanation for example what is the meant by this and why it is so.
3. Or the ones that are somewhat **controversial**, that is ruling that was made was awkward and against the norm of society, what was done was wrong, or the hadith or verse can be mis-interpreted  itself into something else, making it controversial?

What are ethics when asking these three type of question. The reason I am asking this is my question [How many witnesses are required to prove adultery?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1453/witness-in-case-of-adultery) is closed with -3 votes. I think this is a basic question that every Muslim need to know. But the opportunity of answering this question is denied.

Comment: Your original question seems too-localized, and the tone was not good, so I think closing was reasonable.  The question seems better now. Also remember that this is not a fatwa site, if you want a fatwa you should refer to the scholar you follow.The number of witness is 4 not 2 and AFAIR they should be sure that intercourse has happened, the details varies from one scholar to another.

Comment: @Kaveh, The tone was not bad. The question was based on a real event. I am more than willing if someone edits my questions and makes it more useful. But the question here now is what type of question can one ask here? We can talk about the tone in the answer.

Comment: Questions should be interesting for others also, they should not be too localized. Asking for a judgement in such cases also not the right tone since this is not a religious site giving rulings, this is a site about religion.

Comment: Agreed. but my question in current form does not ask for rulings it asks for conditions.

Comment: I have already said the question is better now. :)